# How to config linux nfs mount size?

Tags: linux, file, networking, system, nfs

[image]

Hi. I was connected to linux to windows nfs server.

but it was confirmed by "df" command that it is set incorrectly capacity.

window nfs server capacity is 1.5 TB but linux mount capacity is 250MB

Also the picture below is an automatic mount command in fstab.

[image]

How to resolve that I can do this problem?

In advance, Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: What file system Windows NFS export is formated with ?

Comment: @ShubhangiPardeshi window NFS format is fat32